# how to build tree in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

How to build a tree in EXTJS ? It has to include the images(with '+' & '-' symbols) with respective node.Can you get me the code for the same ????

Answer (score 3):

**Start by defining an Ext.data.TreeStore to load your data into:**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'treeData.json'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Countries',
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

**Json:**

```
[{
"text": "United Kindom",
"children": [{
    "text": "Glasgow",
    "leaf": true
}, {
    "text": "Edinburgh",
    "leaf": true
}, {
    "text": "London",
    "leaf": true
}],
"leaf": false
},
{
    "text": "France",
    "leaf": true
}
...
]
```

**Create the Tree Panel and render it to the document's body:**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Countries &amp; Cities',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    store: store,
    useArrows: false,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'margin: 50px'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the source code for any of the [Ext JS Tree demos](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-6).

[For example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/reorder.html):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    // shorthand
    var Tree = Ext.tree;

    var tree = new Tree.TreePanel({
        useArrows: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        animate: true,
        enableDD: true,
        containerScroll: true,
        border: false,
        // auto create TreeLoader
        dataUrl: 'get-nodes.php',

        root: {
            nodeType: 'async',
            text: 'Ext JS',
            draggable: false,
            id: 'src'
        }
    });

    // render the tree
    tree.render('tree-div');
    tree.getRootNode().expand();
});
```

Comment: @master: there's [another demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html) for that. Did you actually look at the demo pages?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good example:  [static tree](http://extjs.wima.co.uk/example/6) for a static tree.

Saki makes a lot of tutorials and examples that are very helpful for EXTJS.  One of [Saki's Examples](http://examples.extjs.eu/) is an asynchronous tree.  You can find it by looking to the left under state.

This seems like a good tutorial for a dynamic tree with a Ruby on Rails backend: [dynamic tree with RoR backend](http://inside.glnetworks.de/2008/01/26/howto-use-the-ext-js-treeview-exttree-with-ruby-on-rails/).