# How to create tree in Extjs

Tags: extjs

As I am very new to Extjs, I want to know the creation of tree using it. I need a simple example which will create a root and a child to it. Can anyone please help me in it?

Comment: There are numerous examples in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Extjs, you have to know that you can find a lot of example [HERE](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/).
See below for an example with static tree panel :

To get a tree panel to work, you first need to have some data. Loading data through a TreeStore instance will internally parse relationships and apply all tree-related methods to the model instance.

**TreeStore**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
    // Sets up root node
    root : {
        text: 'Root Node',
        expanded : true, // Expands true node on initialization
        children :[{ // Specifies child nodes
            text:'Child 1',
            leaf : true // Specifies node as leaf
        },{
            text:'Child 2',
            leaf : true
        },{
            text : 'Child 3',
            children: [{
                text : 'Grand Child 1',
                children : [{
                    text: 'etc.',
                    leaf : true
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

**TreePanel**

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
    title : 'Title window',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoshow : true,
    height : 200,
    width : 200,
    items : { // Here, you configure your tree panel
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        border : false,
        store : store, // Store created above
        rootVisible : true
    }
});
```

You can find also an example with a JSON file [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079591/how-to-build-tree-in-extjs)